# Discrepancies between Kishimoto and the Asura Path?

Tags: naruto

According to the wiki:

> The Asura Path (修羅道, Shuradō) grants the user the ability to augment their own body to summon mechanised armour and various ballistic and mechanical weaponry.

Two questions on this topic.

1) Kishimoto has said there is no technology in the Naruto universe that would defeat the purpose of ninjas, specifically guns and weapons. However, why did he have the Asura Path of Pain equipped with machine guns, rockets, and lasers? Here's a quote from him:

> Masashi Kishimoto: Firstly, projectile weapons such as guns aren't allowed. (The one exception is Inari's bowgun.) Guns aren't suited to ninja. Gunpowder is used in the anime, though I don't think it should be there. And, vehicles such as aeroplanes are not allowed. I try to restrain technology that can be used for war... For example, if missiles were in it, it'd be the end. (laughs)

It turns out when Pain assaulted the Hidden Leaf Village, it pretty much was the end! So why did he say these things would not be in the Naruto universe when in fact they were?

2) So all the Rinnegan wielders have access to the Six Paths. Does that mean the highly advanced weapons from the Asura Path of Pain originated from the Sage of the Six Paths himself? In other words, did the Sage of the Six paths have some lesser, technologically inferior form of machine guns, rockets, etc. long ago for his Asura Path powers?

Also, what exactly are the powers for people who've wielded the Rinnegan at some point, like Obito, Madara, and Sasuke, regarding the Asura Path? Can they even use it since it involves constructing your own weapons? Or is there something they do to summon these weapons?

Comment: I don't think there's enough evidence to back up all the answers for each of your questions.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Lol. Well, I guess simply Kishimoto made a mistake? Or he lied? I'm not too sure.

Comment: IMO, he didn't plan/think it out. It's clearly contradicting as he states that he would keep the level of technology to minimal and yet he made a character that is something out of Star Wars :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question has two parts, I will do my best to explain them.

(1)

> It turns out when Pain assaulted the Hidden Leaf Village, it pretty much was the end! So why did he say these things would not be in the Naruto universe when in fact they were?

Manga and Anime industry are like comics in western culture. Unlike those from DC, Marvel and other publishers, most of Manga artist (Mangaka) decides how the show is going on. I assume on Marvel or DC, they would need to discuss a lot with plotline for comics.

Also you may have heard about Naruto pilot Manga, which is quite different from current implementation of series. What I am going to say is the "Mangaka" is king of the manga and whatever he says is not planned and will do anything as he desire in his manga, without considering things such as plot holes and others.

Plus with "Boruto" and Ootuski clan being from outer space will make these into making things like it is planned from beginning of series.

(2)

> Also, what exactly are the powers for people who've wielded the Rinnegan at some point, like Obito, Madara, and Sasuke, regarding the Asura Path? Can they even use it since it involves constructing your own weapons? Or is there something they do to summon these weapons?

Well for this one, I have some scene from a book I read earlier. A guy asked "DO you know how strong is batman?" and his friend replied "As far as the author wants to". The same could applied here. I rarely doubt Kishimoto would really planned Obito to imitate as Madara at first place. He may have planned for him to be part of an arc, but not this deep.

Back to question, the only Rinnegan user who extensively use Asura path is, for what I believe,Uzumaki Nagato. Other Rinnegan users are listed but I have never seen any of them using such.

For constructing own weapons, I believe is part of Yin and Yang combined release, not from abilities of Asura path. With ongoing "Boruto" series, your questions will be answered in more detail, so just keep patience. (ง ͠° ͟ل͜ ͡°)ง